# Exception when I use semaphore with current name

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, semaphore

I'm using .net core 2.1 to build a web api. Now face a problem with semaphore. Throwing exception when I set semaphore with a specific name.

A month ago, I deployed semaphore with a name "loginExternal". But now it throws exception. I changed name and deploy, it work again, but when I changed back to old name ("loginExternal"), It throw exception UnauthorizedAccessException  again.

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{

   private readonly Semaphore _semaLogin;

   public UserService()
   {
            // create semaphore
       _semaLogin = new Semaphore(1, 1, "loginExternal"); 
   }

    public async Task<User> ExternalLoginAsync()
    {
       _semaLogin.WaitOne();
       try
       {
          // my code
       }
        finally
       {
           _semaLogin.Release();
       }
    }
}
```

Did I implement semaphore in wrong way? How to solve the current exception? how to prevent it in future?

Comment: You say the issue occurs when you deploy, but not what platform you are deploying it to.

Comment: @PeteKirkham, I deployed it on IIS 10.0. Yesterday it still existed, now it's gone.

Comment: @mjwills, Sorry that I don't remember exception type. The line throws the exception is  _semaLogin.WaitOne(), but its say that exception occurred in constructor of semaphore.

Comment: I try to reproduce it, but I can't. It don't happen anymore.
Yesterday, I tried it in my local, it didn't happen. I deployed it with another semaphore name, I didn't happen too. It's just happen with the same semaphore name in deployed environment.

Comment: @mjwills, do I use semaphore pattern correctly? I guess that error occurred because 1 thread run into semaphore, but it's hang in there.

Comment: @mjwills, I got new clue from a log file. But it mess up my mind, please help me.
System.TypeInitializationException
System.UnauthorizedAccessException : Access to the path is denied.
at System.Threading.Semaphore..ctor(Int32 initialCount, Int32 maximumCount, String name)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()

Comment: This might prove useful to you, the answer is a bit long to include here. Basically, you need to use Semaphore.OpenExisting before attempting to create it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore.openexisting?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea, you are right, exception is UnauthorizedAccessException, but I try to implement like the example, the problem is "SemaphoreSecurity could not be found"? I have google for it, but I haven't have any luck on it.
I am using .net core 2.1. That's so strange.

Comment: And constructor of semaphore doesn't have 4th parameter. (parameter to pass SemaphoreSecurity value)

Comment: @QuangTrần a semaphore isn't a pattern, it's a *local* synchronization primitive. Most of the time it's *not* needed. If you want to ensure that you only call an external service once, it won't help. It won't help if you want only a single instance of your `IUserService`. What are you trying to do? What does `// my code` do and why did you try to use a semaphore around it?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I have a lot of stuff in that code. But I want it to execute one by one. I don't want it overlap request. So I use semaphore for it.

Comment: @QuangTrần why not use a lock then? You are trying to *block* the call, so it doesn't matter how heavy the blocking mechanism is. Make `IUserService` a singleton or scoped service (only you know what it should be) and use a lock on the methods that can't be called concurrently.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, when I test that function,I use postman to call multi request at the same time, and it's cause many problem at '// my code'.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I think lock is the same meaning with semaphore, right?

Comment: @QuangTrần there are better options that blocking though. You can publisher/subscriber (that's an actual pattern) to have multiple callers post a request to a concurrent queue and have a single worker/subscriber process them. An `ActionBlock<T>` implements this already. You could use a hosted service to keep the queues and workers as a long-running service that requests can call. There are many techniques that can help with different service issues

Comment: @QuangTrần lock isn't the same as semaphore. A lock [is a C# statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) that ensures only one thread can enter a code block at a time. Semaphores are lower-level primitives that can be used to implement different kinds of locking.

Comment: I think if any low level mechanism should be used for this it's probably a mutex/machine wide named mutex if the concern is multiple processes interfering at parts of the execution. Although, I have to agree with @PanagiotisKanavos, perhaps there are better ways to implement what you need. by rethinking some processes and models.

Comment: You are right, @QuangTrần, SemaphoreSecurity is not available in .NET Core. My bad for not following through on my research.

Comment: @QuangTrần are you saying that your code fails if multiple requests are made? In that case you should *fix* the code, not cover the problem with a lock. Web applications are concurrent and distributed by nature. **NO** locking mechanism is goind to help you if, for example, you deploy your application to two servers behind a load balancer. Putting a lock the way you imagine can easily kill your application too, if multiple requests arrive and block each other waiting to be served one by one. Blocked requests still take RAM

Comment: @QuangTrần using external login services is provided out of the box with .NET Core as well through ASP.NET Identity, with examples for google, facebook etc available in the project templates themselves

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for reminding me about load balancer. So this can't solve my problem. I found another solution. I don't use semaphore for this case. Thanks all.